# how to add Row view in run time to enter details in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

[click the link I am doing a project for creating Billing Application, how to add row view to enter items, rate, liters, the amount in android studio in run time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJki7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong but you're using TableLayout right?
If you are then just give an id to your table layout and use the following code.
Get the table layout first and instantiate a table row object and set the layout params for the object

```
    final TableLayout productTable = findViewById(R.id.inventory_table);
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Then set the values for the elements in a row and add them to the row

```
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv1.setText(item.getName());
    tableRow.addView(tv1, 1);

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv2.setText(item.getRate());
    tableRow.addView(tv2, 1);
```

I've used getters based on the image you shared above. Anyways after that finally just add the tablerows to your table view

```
    productTable.addView(tableRow);
```

If you're using a loop to add the rows then make sure the second argument in tableRow.addView is the loop's index. E.g.

```
    tableRow.addView(tv2, i);
```

Hope this helps. Kudos